# How to trace the origin of an autocomplete feature, in order to turn it off?

Tags: autocompletion, macvim

Is there any way to trace the source of an auto-complete event within (Mac)Vim? Ie, where within which plugin this is and how it can be turned off?

In my case, I type `{}` in a .tex file and it automatically converts it to `{}<++>`, necessitating an `Esc` `u` to return to the original `{}`. I just want to be able to type `{}` and for the auto-complete event not to occur.

**Note**, although I have this specific problem, I am looking for general information about tracing the origin of such problems.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not autocompletion. You have installed a tex package that comes with abbreviations. See `:help abbreviations`. Use `:verbose abbrev {}` to see where it is defined.

Comment: @romainl You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Hmmm, [this](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim#L52) doesn't look like an abbreviation. `:verbose imap {}` will probably put you on the right track but that plugin seems overly complex to me. Not sure how to disable that specific mapping. You should use it's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

This is due either to an `imap` or an `iabbrev`. You can do either of these to check if there are any current definitions:

```
:[verbose ]imap {}
:[verbose ]iabbrev {}
```

Here, `verbose` is optional and will tell you where things are defined.

---

The particular mapping in your question is defined by [vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex), and as suggested by @romainl in a comment to your question, it is an `imap`. However, the same "problem" could also come from an abbreviation, which is defined with the `:iabbrev`.

For relevant help sections, see:

- `:h :imap`
- `:h :iabbrev`
- `:h :verbose`
- `:h latex-macros`